# Redireccionar a una función en infowindow Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-v3

Quisiera saber cómo puedo redireccionar a una función en infowindow, la función pide el ID, esto son los datos que tengo

```
cellRenderer = { function(cellData, label, rowDatas) { return <a href="#" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title={'<i class="fa fa-history text-primary"/> ' + l.button.goToHistory} id={'LockNumber-' + rowDatas.LockID} onClick={function () { GoLink(cellData, true); }}>{cellData}</a> } }
```

Este es mi infowindow

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString + lockNumber + contentString2 + contentString3 + year + contentString4 
    });


var contentString = '<img src="https://es.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Very-Basic-Lock-icon.png" width="20" heigth="20" /><span class="h4"> #';
var contentString2 = '</span><br>';
var contentString3 = ' &nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/staff-management/512/datetime-128.png" width="20" heigth="20" /><span class="h4"> ';
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con redireccionar  la funcion en infowindow? Explica  un poco mas  lo que deseas hacer.

Comment: @bercklyn Carlosviza a cuando le sea click a un marcador te redireccione por ejemplo a una vista, es decir cuando le doy click al marcador, muestra la información , pero ahora quiero que se redireccione a la información del marcador y eso lo tengo en una función

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo la lógica, esta es la mejor y adecuada forma de resolver el problema.de.redireccionamiento

```
var link = "../LocksHistory/History?Locks=" + lockNumber;

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString + lockNumber + contentString2 + contentString3 + year + contentString4 + "<a href='" + link+"'>Go History</a>"

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo la misma lógica como lo estas trabajando puedes adicionar al código html del content un button el cual cuando lo construyas le  pasarías  las variables que deseas y ejecutar la función en javascript.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString 
});


var contentString = '<img src="https://es.seaicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Very-Basic-Lock-icon.png" width="20" heigth="20" /><span class="h4"> #' +
                    '</span><br>' +
                    ' &nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/staff-management/512/datetime-128.png" width="20" heigth="20" /><span class="h4"> ' +
                    '<button type="button" onclick="MyFunction(' + param1 + ',' + param2 + ');">Hazme Click</button>';
```

De ahí llamarías a tu función en javascript (si deseas que sea una simple redirección te recomiendo que uses un actionlink)

Comment: acabó de guiarme en lo que planteas, pero al hacerlo me dice que es indefinido, si encuentra el ID correcto, también hice una prueba instanciando la función y se entra al seleccionarlo , instancia `var local = new function (ID)`  lo redireccione de esta manera y me marca error de indefinido `var his ='<button type="button" onclick="function('+ID+');">Go</button>';`

Comment: gracias ya lo pude resolver

Comment: @Daniel ¿Mi respuesta fue de ayuda? De ser si la respuesta  me harias el favor de marcarla como la mejor =) .

Comment: @Daniel en lugar de editar esta respuesta, mejor añade la tuya. Pasadas 48 horas podrás aceptarla.